# Collapsing some fields in add content page

Tags: entities, theming, nodes

I want to use the drupal Collapse style for some fields.
For example: while writing a story in my drupal 7 site, on the content publishing form user will has an option like **"I want to sell this story"**
Now, if the user click on it then some filed's will show-up like [**Story Price**] [**Story License**] [**Topic Summary**], so that they can provide all those necessary information's to sell the story. Either, if the user don't want to sell the story, they need not face those fields instead of **"I want to sell this story"** link! Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Read http://bit.ly/XHhQad. Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Field group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module. You can set field group settings "collapsed" and deselect "Mark group for required fields". It collapsed the field group by default.

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.